# What is the count code in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework, I know count code in SQL but what is that in EF?

```
select COUNT(*) 
from Factor f
left join FactorItems FI on f.FactorID=FI.FactorRef
```

and this is my entity code:

```
var CountOfitem = (from FI in context.FactorItems
                   join P in context.tblparts on FI.PartRef equals P.PartsID
                   where (FI.FactorRef == FactorID)
                   select new
                            {
                                gridcount = FI.Rowno
                            }
```

How can I get count in my `select new` ?

Comment: How about `Count`. Easier if you use the fluent API instead of the query one

Comment: dear @BradleyDotNET I can't get you what is the fulent API? what is the code?

Comment: @AliEshghi fluent API:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
var CountOfitem= (from FI in context.FactorItems
                  join P in context.tblparts on FI.PartRef equals P.PartsID
                  where (FI.FactorRef == FactorID)
                  select new 
                      {
                          gridcount=FI.Rowno
                       }).Count();
```

to get the number of items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of `FactorItems`, simply write:

```
var count = context.FactorItems.Count()
```

or

```
var count = context.FactorItems.Where(...).Select(...).Count()
```

Comment: this ignores the fact that he wants to filter FactorItems.FactorRef on FactorID